# Ugly shadows on button, Blendmode not working

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to implement a SwiftUI neomorphic button in SwiftUI but the shadows are messed up. To fix it, I use blendmode(overlay), but it has no effect on the button in NavBar. It works fine on the button in the regular view. [The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDcaJ.jpg)

Here’s my code

```
struct ContentView: View {

var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
            
            Button("Hi") { }
                .foregroundColor(Color.primary)
                .padding()
                .background(
                    ZStack {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12, style: .continuous)
                            .shadow(
                                color: .white,
                                radius: 12,
                                x: -6,
                                y: -8
                        )
                            .shadow(
                                color: Color.black.opacity(0.8),
                                radius: 12,
                                x: 6,
                                y: 8
                        )
                            .blendMode(.overlay)
                            .padding(2)
                        
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12, style: .continuous)
                            .foregroundColor(color)
                    }
            )
        .navigationBarColor(UIbackground)
        .navigationBarTitle("SwiftUI")
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity,
                   minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity,
                   alignment: .center)
            .background(color)
            .navigationBarItems(leading: Button("Hi") { }
                .foregroundColor(Color.primary)
                .padding()
                .background(
                    ZStack {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12, style: .continuous)
                            .shadow(
                                color: .white,
                                radius: 12,
                                x: -6,
                                y: -8
                        )
                            .shadow(
                                color: Color.black.opacity(0.8),
                                radius: 12,
                                x: 6,
                                y: 8
                        )
                            .blendMode(.overlay)
                            .padding(2)
                        
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12, style: .continuous)
                            .foregroundColor(color)
                    }
            ))
        
    }
} 
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.